# jQuery mobile only use one Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile

im using jQuery mobile for the first time. I only want to use the swipe event(https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/) of jQuery mobile, but it has some other effects on my WordPress website. I want to just call a function when the user swipes my slider.

Problem is jQuery mobile seems to change some things especially in styling. My toggle switch checkboxes get split up into switch and checkbox and my navbar links don't work anymore.

I googled and found a solution to the checkbox problem with data-role="none". But its really annoying to put data-role="none" everywhere I want to disable jQuery mobile.

Is there a way to only use the swipe event and ignore everything else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just learn about the [native touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events) and forget about JQuery for something so trivial.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Thanks a lot, seems to be a way better solution for what i want.